# Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb:

Tags: android, emulator

I'm not even 100% sure how this error started but I am unable to run my project on an emulator at the moment.

Versions:

- Android Studio: 3.4.1
- Emulator: Pie API 28
- Expo SDK: 32.0.6
- Expo CLI: 2.19.4

General workflow is to open the emulator and make sure it is up and running.

Go to the command line and hit `expo start` wait for the initialisation and then hit `a`

Upon doing so I now get the error

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb:
```

After lots of searching the internet I cannot find any other reference to this specific error. There are plenty of examples of when further information is posted after the "Error running adb:" bit including no device, adb not installed, etc., but nothing that is an empty error message.

- I've tried uninstalling Android Studio.
- I've removed all Android Studio registry entries.
- I've tried installing the platform tools independently from Android Studio.

I'm at a loss on where to go with this as there seems to be little information out there on where to go next.

Any ideas or help very welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wipe your virtual device data from AVD Manager.

Comment: Please provide instructions for doing this. … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Andy4wardcomputech

I have solved the same error for my project.Try it for your one as well.

Try to open the emulator and if you are getting an error saying adb.exe is obsolete in a pop-up.

Open Android studio> SDK Manager>SDK Tools
Check for any update Android SDK Build-Tools if the status is Update Available. Kindly update it your problem will solve.

If the status is Installed then click on Show Package Details at the bottom right corner.
Scroll down and check whether the latest version is installed and remove all the older versions. Reboot your system and try to execute your project in emulator it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe your device data by first opening Android Studio then clicking on the more actions link. Then click on "AVD Manager" and that will bring you to "Your Virtual Devices" Next in the table look for the heading titled "Actions" and click on the rightmost arrow and that will make a dropdown where you can choose to wipe the data.

[image]

Comment: This also worked for a similar problem with `expo run:android` for some reason

Answer (score -1):

I looked everywhere for this issue and what worked for me was instead of running the app through power shell which is provided in VS Code as well I used windows command prompt and instead of npm start I used expo start which worked for me and I was able to run app on android emulator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).